# Add Null date 0Nd to date column for empty cells in kdb

Tags: kdb

trying to update empty cells with null date i.e 0Nd for Date column
`data: update date:0Nd^date from data where product not like "Debet:Loan";`

Note: column type is date

| Class | product | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | Debet:Instru:* |  |
| First | Debet:Instru:* |  |
| First | Debet:Loan | 2020.10.12 |
| First | Debet:Loan | 2020.10.12 |

after change the table should look like

| Class | product | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | Debet:Instru:* | 0Nd |
| First | Debet:Instru:* | 0Nd |
| First | Debet:Loan | 2020.10.12 |
| First | Debet:Loan | 2020.10.12 |

Comment: In tables, date cells equal to null are printed as empty (as shown in your top table). I do expect null[t[date]] called on your table will output 1100b and t date will output "0N 0N 2020.10.12 2020.10.12", correct? `0Nd^date` does not get the desired output because the first 2 dates are already null

Comment: No not excatly, its show the empty cells it self. I want empty cells should be filled with 0Nd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion here lies in the fact that the console will display a cell as empty if it is null AND the datatype of the column (a list) is not mixed.

For example:

```
q)0Nd~first 0N 2021.01.01d
1b
```

the null here is actually of type 0Nd as the list is of type date. You can think of this as similar to the way the console will display a list of floats that are whole numbers -  the f in this case is assumed or "inherited" by the last element in the list >

```
q)`float$1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4f
```

If you truly want to have 0Nd DISPLAYED in your table you would have to make the column a mixed list - thus forcing the console to show you the exact type of Null as you cannot assume it based on the type of the column:

```
q)([]a: 1 2 3;date:(0Nd;10;2021.01.01d))
a date
------------
1 0Nd
2 10
3 2021.01.01
```

Please dont do this  - the null in a column which displays as an empty cell is 0Nd even though it is not explicitly shown in the console or might appear as 0N in a list of dates e.g  `0N 2021.01.01 2022.01.01`

```
q)t:([]a: 1 2 3;date:(0Nd;2021.10.10;2021.01.01d))
q)t
a date
------------
1
2 2021.10.10
3 2021.01.01
q)exec date from t
0N 2021.10.10 2021.01.01
q)first exec date from t
0Nd
```

Thanks